# How can I check to see if a task is ran as a dependency of another task in gulp@4?

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

I use `gulp-notify` to trigger notifications when tasks complete. If a task is ran standalone, a notification for that specific task is triggered. If a task is ran as a dependency of another task, a notification for all dependencies is triggered.

In gulp@3, I check if the task is being called as a dependency using `gulp.seq`, which contains an array of the tasks being ran. Let's say I have three tasks: `default`, `styles`, and `scripts`, with the later two set as dependencies of the first. When running `gulp styles`, `gulp.seq` will contain `[ 'styles' ]`. When running `gulp` (the default task), `gulp.seq` will contain `[ 'styles', 'scripts', 'default' ]`. Knowing that, I then check `gulp.seq.indexOf("styles") > gulp.seq.indexOf("default")`, which tells me weather or not `styles` was ran as part of the `default` task.

With gulp@4, it appears that `gulp.seq` no longer exists. I've tried digging through the documentation and source code with no luck. It seems like `gulp.tree({ deep:true })` ([docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/api/tree.md)) might be what I'm looking for, but I don't see anything in it that returns anything useful.

Is there an equivalent of `gulp.seq` in gulp@4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a bit of luck, I discovered this was possible via the module [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs), which I already have installed.

When running `gulp styles`, for example, I can check `argv._.indexOf("styles") > -1`, as it contains `['styles']`. When running `gulp` (i.e the default task), it contains `[]`. In my testing, this works perfectly for my use case.

Comment: Nice solution - it can be a little bit nicer using `includes` instead of `indexOf`: `argv._.includes("styles")`

Answer (score 1):

The API `gulp.seq` was never an official `prop` exposed by Gulp. With Gulp 4, you cannot do that. `gulp.tree({ /* */ })` will not solve this problem for you.

Having said that, if you still need to find whether a task has run during some other task's pipeline, then you will have to decorate every gulp task with your own wrapper using something like this:

```
let runTasks = [];

function taskWrapper(taskName, tasks, thisTask) {

    let callbackTask;

    function innerCallback(cb) {
        runTasks.push(taskName);
        cb();
    }

    if (thisTask) {
        callbackTask = function(cb) {
            thisTask(function () {
                innerCallback(cb);
            });
        }
    } else {
        callbackTask = innerCallback;
    }

    const newTasks = [ ...tasks, callbackTask ];

    gulp.task(taskName, gulp.series(newTasks));
}

// INSTEAD OF THIS
// gulp.task('default', gulp.series('style', 'script', function () { }));

// DO THIS
taskWrapper('default', ['style', 'script'], function(cb) {
    console.log('default task starting');
    cb();
});
```

NOTE: Above code snippets has limitation. If you use watch mode, array maintaining the executed tasks i.e. `runTasks` will keep on growing. Also, **it assumes tasks will always run in series.** For a parallel mode, the logic gets little complicated.

Finally, you can also have a `predefault` task to help it further:

```
taskWrapper('predefault', [], function(cb) {
    // RESET runTasks
    runTasks = [];
    cb();
});

taskWrapper('default', ['predefault', 'style', 'script'], function(cb) {
    console.log('default task starting');
    cb();
});
```

Also, I am doubtful if `gulp-notify` will work with Gulp 4.

Comment: Interesting, this gives me ideas on how to at least test this. Running in parallel would be ideal, but I can try to figure that out myself.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, but I figured out how to do this very little change to my existing code.